# jQuery click event only working in landscape(iPad)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad

I have a click event that only works when I have my iPad in landscape but when I turn it to portrait, it stops working.  Can anyone tell me why?

```
<div id="home_page">
    <div class="full">
        <button class="button" id="func_checks">Functional Checks</button>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#func_checks").on("click touchstart", function(){
        $("#header").append("<h1>G-IV Functional Checks</h1>");
        $("#home_page").hide();
        $(".return").show();
        $("#checks_page").show();
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify click handler to:

```
$("#func_checks").on("click touchstart", function(){
    $("#header").append("<h1>G-IV Functional Checks</h1>");
    $("#home_page").hide();
    $(".return").show();
    $("#checks_page").show();
});
```

Comment: This actually doesn't work, it's doing the same thing.  Also, `.on` is preferred over `.bind` as of jQuery 1.7

Comment: Gotcha.  I added the touchstart event and it's still not working in portrait.  I'll edit my question to reflect that.

Comment: @Robert: that is what worked for me. i would suggest you to look into thia articles http://www.danwellman.co.uk/fixing-jquery-click-events-for-the-ipad/ and http://www.mitch-solutions.com/blog/17-ipad-jquery-live-click-events-not-working. see if it helps

Comment: You'll laugh at the reason why, I did.  Although it was more of an FML laugh on my part.  I had a header element that was overlapping the button whenever I turned the tablet to portrait view.  Once I fixed that, it worked.  I'm accepting your answer and thanks very much for the resource you provided